# I want to show all text data after click text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my code I truncate text by 15 characters But I want to show remaining text after the click on the text
[image]

How can I show remaining text after clicking on the text?

```js
$('#show_data').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var Id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('user-id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/accounts/AccountController/viewEnableEmp",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      Id: Id,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#address').text(data[0]['user_address'].substring(0, 15));
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("error message" + data);
    },
    async: false,
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group row col-4">
  <label>Address :</label>
  <p id="address" style="margin-left: 10px;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that using `async: false` is very bad practice and should be removed. You don't need it in any case as you're using the callback pattern. Also, remove the inline styling and put it in an external stylesheet.

With regard to the issue at hand, when the AJAX request completes add two `data` attributes to the `#address` element. One containing the short address and one with the full address. You can then toggle between these values in the `text()` of the element when it's clicked, based on a class. Try this:

```
// AJAX example:
success: function(data) {
  var address = data[0]['user_address'];
  var shortAddress = address.substring(0, 15);

  $('#address').data({
     addr: address,
     shortaddr: shortAddress
  }).text(shortAddr);
},
```

```js
$('#address').on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.text(function() {
    $el.toggleClass('open');
    return $el.hasClass('open') ? $el.data('addr') : $el.data('shortaddr');
  });
});
```

```css
#address { margin-left: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row col-4">
  <label>Address:</label>
  <p id="address" data-addr="42 Wallaby Way, Sydney" data-shortaddr="42 Wallaby Way">42 Wallaby Way</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just split it with a span that can be toggled

Comment: True, probably simpler in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

Replace

```
$('#address').text(data[0]['user_address'].substring(0, 15));
```

with this:

```js
let addr = `Here is a string that is more than 15 chars long`; //  data[0]['user_address'];
$('#address').html(addr.substring(0, 15)+`<span>${addr.substring(15)}</span>`);


// somewhere else in the script
$("#address").on("click",function() {
  $(this).find("span").show(); // or .toggle() 
})
```

```css
#address>span { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="address"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

the simplest way to do this would be to add an on click event listener to refetch the data without the substring

```
      $('#address').text(data[0]['user_address'].substring(0,15));
```

editted:

add this to the script tag

```
$('#address').on('click', function(e) {
  var Id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('user-id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/accounts/AccountController/viewEnableEmp",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      Id: Id,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#address').text(data[0]['user_address'].substring(0, 30));
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("error message" + data);
    },
    async: false,
  });
});
```

Comment: @Devid Ko I have a total of 30 characters after substring use it shows 15 characters   I want to show the remaining 15 characters after the click on text

Comment: i updated the answer, you basically add an on click function to the html element that re-fetches the data

Comment: This will just add another event handler to the `#address` element which then fights the first one. This answercreates more problems than it solves.

Comment: but thats what he wanted?

"I want to show remaining text after the click on the text"